# running file when opening jupyter console with ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.file_to_run

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

From the documentation (`jupyter console --help-all` in a terminal), it seems that entering 
`jupyter console --ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.file_to_run='name_of_file'` in a terminal should open a jupyter console, and run the specified file.

However, if I prepare a test file:

```
# python file named 'test.py'
a = 101
```

and run the following command in my command prompt

```
jupyter console --ZMQTerminalIPythonApp.file_to_run='test.py'`
```

And then try the following command in the ipython terminal that opens:

```
a
```

I get a NameError telling me that a is not defined.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ```
$ jupyter --version
4.1.0
```
no longer seem to have ```file_to_run```